# Avoid replacing of space in filename with underscore while uploading

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload

I have a form in Codeigniter in which I am uploading a file. If the file name contains space eg: *images (1).jpg* then, it is getting uploaded in the secure folder as *images_(1).jpg*. How to avoid this? I want to upload it with the same name of the image eg: *images (1).jpg*.

I have used `trim()` while accessing the file name as:

```
$thumbfile=trim($_FILES['thumb_image']['name']);
```

For file uploading, I have used the following section of code :

```
$config1['upload_path'] = './secure/'.$lastid;
$ext = end(explode(".", $_FILES['thumb_image']['name']));
$config1['file_name'] = trim($_FILES['thumb_image']['name']);
$config1['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|png|jpeg|gif|bmp|jpe|tiff|tif';
$this->load->library('upload', $config1);
```

Can anyone help me to solve this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is the default functionality of Codeigniter's upload library. Due to this fact, you will have to hack the codeigniter core.

Comment: try $thumbfile = str_replace(' ', ' ', $_FILES['thumb_image']['name']);

Comment: @MohitJain It didn't worked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `$config['remove_spaces'] = FALSE;`

Otherwise, look in the core upload library where you'll see the `$this->file_name = preg_replace("/\s+/", "_", $this->file_name);` in the `do_upload` method which you can alter.